# Flash/Actionscript 3 - import/embed XML file for export?

Tags: xml, flash, import, export

How do I import or embed an XML file so I can export a 100% independent SWF? My project reads an external XML file for text fields and images. When I export the SWF, none of the images/text will show unless I have the XML file in the same directory. I want a 100% independent SWF without the need for the XML.

Here is what I have so far, this code is from a tutorial:

```
var imageArray:Array = new Array();
var painterArray:Array = new Array();
var titleArray:Array = new Array();
var dateArray:Array = new Array();

//Loader event for the XML
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

var xml:XML;

loader.load(new URLRequest("mday.xml"));

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    //load XML
    xml=new XML(e.target.data);
    var il:XMLList=xml.images;
    listLength=il.length();
    //fill up the array from XML
    populateArray();
}

function populateArray():void {
    //takes the properties defined in the XML and stores them into arrays
    var i:Number;
    for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        imageArray[i]=xml.images[i].pic;
        titleArray[i]=xml.images[i].title;
        painterArray[i]=xml.images[i].painter;
        dateArray[i]=xml.images[i].date;
    }
}
```

**The AS is attached to a keyframe, not in its separate class.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of loading in an external xml file you will have a variable that contains all of the xml data:

```
var imageArray:Array = new Array();
var painterArray:Array = new Array();
var titleArray:Array = new Array();
var dateArray:Array = new Array();

//assign all your xml to your xml variable. Here is some example xml data
var xml:XML = <gallery>
<image name="school">image1.jpg</image>
<image name="garden">image2.jpg</image>
<image name="shop">image3.jpg</image>
</gallery>;

load();//call your load function

function load():void {

    var il:XMLList=xml.images;
    listLength=il.length();
    //fill up the array from XML
    populateArray();
}

function populateArray():void {
    //takes the properties defined in the XML and stores them into arrays
    var i:Number;
    for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        imageArray[i]=xml.images[i].pic;
        titleArray[i]=xml.images[i].title;
        painterArray[i]=xml.images[i].painter;
        dateArray[i]=xml.images[i].date;
    }
}
```